# filter cards in Bootstrap 4 using buttons

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I have a landing page with 40 cards. Each card is assigned to a category/group (5 categories in total). I'd like to create  5 buttons so once the button is clicked cards from specific category or categories are visible. I don't want to use search bar. Only these 5 buttons tofilter the group of cards.

I am using Bootstrap 4 and Flask. I found few solutions. One of them is [here](https://www.codeply.com/go/KvTSAFv2bv) but it uses a search bar instead of buttons. Could you please advise me on how to do it?

Comment: this would be better done in JS than in flask. Maintain the list of cards in JS and on button click you can filter the cards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JavaScript method `querySelectorAll()` to get all the cards and then use an if statement to toggle the visibility of the cards by category.

### Try the following snippets

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
  for(card of cards){
    
    const cardCategory = card.getAttribute('category');
    const categoryOne = this.getAttribute('category-one');
    const categoryTwo = this.getAttribute('category-two');
    
    if(cardCategory ===  categoryOne || cardCategory ===  categoryTwo || categoryOne === 'all'){
      card.style.display = 'block';
    } else{
      card.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
});
```

```css
section{display:flex}
.card{
width:70px;
height:100px;
border:1px solid black;
margin:4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="card" category="cars" style="background-color:yellow"></div>
  <div class="card" category="cars" style="background-color:yellow"></div>
  <div class="card" category="apples" style="background-color:red"></div>
  <div class="card" category="trucks" style="background-color:green"></div>
  <div class="card" category="trucks" style="background-color:green"></div>
  <div class="card" category="trucks" style="background-color:green"></div>
</section>
<br>
<button category-one="cars">Cars</button>
<button category-one="apples">Apples</button>
<button category-one="trucks">Trucks</button>
<button category-one="trucks" category-two="apples">Trucks and Apples</button>
<button category-one="all">Show All</button>
```

It's also possible to achieve this by using the `filter()` method:

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  
  const cards = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.card'));
  
  for(card of cards){
    card.style.display = 'none'; 
  }
  
  const categoryOne = this.getAttribute('category-one');
  const categoryTwo = this.getAttribute('category-two'); 
  
  const result = cards.filter(card => card.getAttribute('category') === categoryOne || card.getAttribute('category') === categoryTwo || categoryOne === 'all');
  
  for(card of result){
    card.style.display = 'block';
  }
  
});
```

```css
section{display:flex}
.card{
width:70px;
height:100px;
border:1px solid black;
margin:4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="card" category="cars" style="background-color:yellow"></div>
  <div class="card" category="cars" style="background-color:yellow"></div>
  <div class="card" category="apples" style="background-color:red"></div>
  <div class="card" category="trucks" style="background-color:green"></div>
  <div class="card" category="trucks" style="background-color:green"></div>
  <div class="card" category="trucks" style="background-color:green"></div>
</section>
<br>
<button category-one="cars">Cars</button>
<button category-one="apples">Apples</button>
<button category-one="trucks">Trucks</button>
<button category-one="trucks" category-two="apples">Trucks and Apples</button>
<button category-one="all">Show All</button>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the example. Is it complicated to implement multiple selections in such filter. I am looking for some solution but I am not good at js and I am struggling with it.

Comment: What do you mean? You need a better explanation of how this code works? Also, what do you mean with: "Is it complicated to implement multiple selections in such filter"?

Comment: For now you can filter only 1 category at the same time. My question is more related to if it is easy to implement filter that allows user to choose more than 1 option at the same time so Category 1 and 2 can be selected.

Comment: Sure, I will add a button to filter 2 categories

Comment: I just modified the code, try it.